# Vba Excel Deleting a line from a table using an userform

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform that allows the user to create new lines (rows) or to change the values in those lines. However now I'm trying to add the option for the user to remove the line from the table and from the table only. Meaning: I don't want the entire line from the excel sheet getting deleted, I only want to delete the part that is within the columns of the table.

It would go something like this: User inputs variable, code finds the variable in the table and therefore identifying the line, after that the entire row (inside the table) gets deleted.

my code right now is like this:

```
'To Remove

mid2:

Dim NE2 As Integer
Dim numNE2 As String



Sheets("Máquinas").Select
LastNE2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Máquinas").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

For NE2 = 3 To LastNE2
numNE2 = Cells(NE2, 1)


If Box1 = "" Then
MsgBox "Equipment Number Missing."
GoTo fimv
ElseIf Box1 = numNE2 Then
GoTo jumpNE2
End If

If NE2 = LastNE2 Then
MsgBox "Equipment number non existent"
GoTo fimv
End If

Next NE2

jumpNE2:


Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela2")

tbl.ListRows(NE2).Delete
```

If i change that NE in the last line for a number it works however i don't know what's the number every time the user chooses to change something. That said number is inside the variable NE2.

Edit: Solved.

added a variable as long named NEX and then declared that NEX=NE-2
After that used the NEX inside of the tbl.ListRows(NEX).Delete   like this and now it fully works! Thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look at `ListObjects` - they are the actual tables you use in Excel, and are much more versatile than manually adding and removing rows in the worksheet

Comment: But for instance i got a piece of code that is supposed to delete the row however i don't know how to specify the row that i want to be deleted. 

The variable NE holds the number of the row however when i try to write
tbl.ListRows(NE).Delete it gives me an error and i have no clue what i'm doing wrong

Comment: For instance if i try tbl.ListRows(264).Delete it is working however it won't always be the row 264 that has to be deleted. The number of the row is being held by the variable NE and my doubt is how can i transfer that value to that place or how do i use the variable in that formula.

Comment: It's always good practice to post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask a question on SO, as it allows people to see where you've gone wrong, and that you've put in an effort to try and solve it. From the sound of it, you've got some code already that's not working as expected? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54887201/edit) your question with the specific issue and we can go from there:)

Comment: Thanks, just edited the post and added that part of the code